# How do I refresh TextView on activity calling after closing alert dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog that allows user to edit a TextView. Currently, once the alert dialog closes, the user has to hit the back button and then re-enter the activity for the TextView to update. I've tried many solutions on SO but none seem to work. When the user clicks 'Save Changes', the TextView should update.

Calling activity:

```
package com.group1.workouttracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class DayActivity extends Activity {
    //does not extend ListActivity, so list functions must be called by myList object

    private String buttonClicked;
    private String thisSummary;
    private Intent intent;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_day);

        db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        intent = getIntent();
        buttonClicked = intent.getStringExtra("Day");

        Button buttonCreateExercise = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddExercise);
        buttonCreateExercise.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerCreateExercise(buttonClicked));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void readSummary(String buttonClicked) {
        TextView textViewSummary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSummary);
        textViewSummary.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListenerEditSummary(buttonClicked));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        thisSummary = db.readSummary(buttonClicked).getSummary();
        TextView summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSummary);
        summary.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListenerEditSummary(buttonClicked));
        summary.setText(thisSummary);
    }
}
```

Alert Dialog that activates on a long press:

```
package com.group1.workouttracker;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnLongClickListenerEditSummary implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    Context context;
    String dayClicked = "";

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        context = view.getContext();

        final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        ObjectDay objectDay = db.readSummary(dayClicked);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_summary_form, null, false);

        final long dayId = objectDay.getId();
        final String dName = objectDay.getDayName();
        final EditText editTextSummary = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSummary);

        final CharSequence[] items = { "Edit", "Delete" };

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Exercise");
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(formElementsView)
                .setTitle("Edit Summary for " + dayClicked + ":")
                .setPositiveButton("Save Changes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                ObjectDay objectDay = new ObjectDay();
                                objectDay.setId(dayId);
                                objectDay.setDayName(dName);
                                objectDay.setSummary(editTextSummary.getText().toString());

                                boolean updateSuccessful = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).updateSummary(objectDay);

                                if(updateSuccessful) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Summary was updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to update summary.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                //dialog.cancel();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        }).show();

        return false;
    }

    public void editRecord(final String dName) {

        final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        ObjectDay objectDay = db.readSummary(dName);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_summary_form, null, false);

        final EditText editTextDay = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSummary);
        final EditText editTextSummary = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSummary);

        editTextSummary.setText(objectDay.getSummary());
    }

    public OnLongClickListenerEditSummary(String dayClicked) {
        this.dayClicked = dayClicked;
    }

}
```

Edit: I was able to get this working correctly by adding the following code:

Activity:

```
public void passThrough(ObjectDay objDay) {
    textViewSummary.setText(objDay.getSummary());
}
```

In .setpositive button:

```
((DayActivity) context).passThrough(objectDay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a dialog wont trigger the Activity's onPause/onResume (I'm not sure if that's true for dialog fragments). Instead you can apply an [onDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) (which can be a member variable of the Activity or anonymous) to the dialog.

When the dialog is closed (by any means) you'll get some information and you can update your textfield. Alternatively you could do the same from the positive click listener.

Either

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //UPDATE FROM HERE (call a method or manipulate an Activity member var)
    }
});
```

OR

```
alert.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        //UPDATE FROM HERE (Check DialogInterface  for positive if you want)
    }
});
```

Edit, for your example:

```
class Whatever extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private MyPassThroughListener mPassThroughListener = new MyPassThroughListener() {
           @Override
           public function passThrough(ObjectDay objDay) {
                  mTextView.setText(objDay.getSummary());    
           }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        buttonCreateExercise.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerCreateExercise(mPassThroughListener ));


    }

}

class OnLongClickListenerEditSummary {
   MyPassThroughListener mPassThroughListener;
   ...

   public OnLongClickListenerEditSummary (MyPassThroughListener passThroughListener) {
       mPassThroughListener = passThroughListener;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
      ....

       new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setPositiveButton("Save Changes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            ObjectDay objectDay = new ObjectDay();
                            objectDay.setId(dayId);
                            objectDay.setDayName(dName);
                            objectDay.setSummary(editTextSummary.getText().toString());

                            mPassThroughListener.passThrough(objectDay);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

     ...
}
```

}

public interface MyPassThroughListener {
     public function passThrough(ObjectDay objDay);
}

Comment: I understand this but what exactly can I put in the positive click listener to accomplish what I need? I've been trying different things and nothing has worked yet.

Comment: I would keep your text view as an Activity member variable, you can use it directly from inside the onClick (as long as the alert is declared within the scope of the activity)

Comment: Well I think the issue is that the textview is generated from a query from an SQLite database. I need to requery without backing out. This is my problem.

Comment: I've just edited this answer with a solution which will work for you. I haven't given things good names but it should get you on track and the best part is no extra db call